# Loading Date Part as YYYY

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have an input csv which has a date field . The date field contains the year as either 16 or 0016. In any of these cases, I need the date to be loaded to target table with year as 2016 using sql loader
Is there any way out for this in control file ?

Comment: I need to load using control file.. apologies for missing out on this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pick up the last two characters and append 20 in the beginning? If this is the exact requirement, you can easily achieve this.

Or better to use a variable for that field, and you can change the value at the time of insertion. something like this:-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(column1, @var1, column3, ...)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Hi Shashwat .. can we achieve this via control file ?

Comment: I haven't used control files much, but yes we can do this via control files as well. I remember someone using this type of manipulations on the data. I won't be able to give you exact solution, but yes, this can be achieved.

Comment: To be more specific , if I have an input date like 21/10/16 or 21/10/0016, i need the date to be loaded as 21/10/2016 . And i need to achieve this in the control file itself for sql loader.

Comment: you can use something like this:- LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(column1, @var1, column3, ...)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%Y%m%d')

Answer (score 0):

The line for that column in the control file could look like this:

```
   ,load_date date "to_date(regexp_replace(:load_date, '^(.*/).*?(.{2}$)','\\1\\2'), 'DD/MM/RRRR')"
```

Use REGEXP_REPLACE to save the first part of the date up to and including the last slash and the last 2 characters (effectively removing the 00 part of the year if it exists).  Then format to a date using the 'RRRR' for the year which lets Oracle put in the right century. Note you have to quote the backslashes in the control file when referring to the remembered groups of the regex.